# running a jquery task forever

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new in jQuery / java script; trying to make a slider. Please help with the following problem.

I want to make a div (class is slider) fade-out and fade-in forever; please check this code.
Is it possible to use setInterval() function for this?

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Slider</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="../jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        .slider1{
            width: 500px;
            height: 250px;  
            margin: 0 auto;
            background-image: url(images/rectblue.png);
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var runForever = $(document).ready(function () {

            $(".slider1").fadeOut(2000, function () {
                $(".slider1").fadeIn(2000);
            });

        });

        runForever();
        //setInterval(runForever, 4000);
        //This runs the function 'runForever' one time only, how to run it every 4 sec? 
        //the above commented out code does not work.

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="slider1"></div>        
</body>
```

Comment: Why not keep the script code inside a function,then use setTimeout for 4 seconds, and at end of it call the function again, this way it will keep looping until you clear interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't define `runforever` as a function, you made it the result of the call to `$(document).ready`. If you define it as a function and put it in a `setInterval`, it works.

```
var flashSlider = function () {
    $(".slider1").fadeOut(2000, function () {
        $(".slider1").fadeIn(2000);
    });
};
$(document).ready(function () {
    setInterval(flashSlider, 4000);
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uoqdfhdb/

I think it's a little more jQuery-elegant to write the flash-forever recursively:

```
var flashForever = function () {
    $(".slider1").fadeOut(2000).fadeIn(2000, flashForever);
};
$(document).ready(function () {
    flashForever();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uoqdfhdb/1/

Except I wonder if the tail-recursion will eventually cause stack overflow.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
var $slider = $('.slider1');
var flashSlider = function () {
  $slider.fadeToggle(2000, flashSlider);
};

$(document).ready(function () {
  flashSlider();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
      var $slider1 =  $(".slider1");
      function runForever(){
          $slider1.fadeOut(2000, function () {
            $slider1.fadeIn(2000);
          });
          clearTimeout(t);
          var t = setTimeout(runForever, 4000);
     }
     runForever();
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.  You should put all of your code in $(document).ready argument for the callback function, you can't capture that as a function.  It is a listener on the document object to make sure everything is loaded.  So it should look something like:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var runForever= function()
        {
          $(".slider1").fadeOut(2000, function () {
              $(".slider1").fadeIn(2000);
          });
        }

      setInterval(runForever, 4000);
      //This runs the function 'runForever' one time only, how to run it every 4 sec? 
      //the above commented out code does not work.
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Just let me rewrite your code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var runForever = function() {
        $(".slider1").fadeOut(2000, function() {
            $(".slider1").fadeIn(2000);
        });
    }
    runForever();
    setInterval(function(){runForever();}, 4000);
});
```

Here is a [live preview](https://jsfiddle.net/7ag216n0/)

you could also write a recursive function calling itself again and again after completing animation:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var runForever = function() {
        $(".slider1").fadeOut(2000, function() {
            $(".slider1").fadeIn(2000, function(){
                runForever();
            });
        });
    }
    runForever();
});
```